# In Visual Studio, when would I want to use the Test View?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

For managing unit tests in Visual Studio, I use the Test List Editor. There's also a Test View which looks similar but more limited. **When would I want to use the Test View as opposed to the Test List Editor or any of the other test windows?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the test view is a nice compact list that fits better on screen(if i need it on screen at all) as i use a seperate portrait monitor for most of the vs tool windows.